# How does After Trigger works when using addError in ContentVersion object? Is the file successfully uploaded or not?

Tags: trigger, files, after-trigger, contentversion, fileupload

I have a custom object with related files in a page layout. Now if user click the 'Upload files', I want to prevent user to upload a file.

Seems like I cannot use 'before trigger' because I cannot query the ContentDocumentId in ContentDocumentLink to write a condition. My understanding is using 'after trigger', the record is already committed to the database which sounds like a problem also.

```
public class FileHandler {  
    public static void preventFileDownload(List<ContentVersion> contVer) {
        for(ContentVersion cv : contVer) {            
            System.debug('getId: ' + cv.ContentDocumentId); // I got Id : 0692w00000NI9TuAAL
            if(cv.ContentSize >= 0) {
                cv.addError('Ooops, you cannot download the file.');
            }                       
        }
    }
}

trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    
    if(trigger.isInsert) {
        if(trigger.isAfter) {
            FileHandler.preventFileDownload(trigger.new);
        }
    }
    
}
```

When I query using the anonymous window, I got the 'ContentDocument'

```
Id x1 = '0692w00000NI9TuAAL';
System.debug(x1.getSObjectType()); //ContentDocument
```

But when I query the ContentDocument.. no records is also showing. So is the file uploaded successfully anywhere or not? and How can I access the variable 'x1' if it doesn't exist?

```
SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentDocument
```

Comment: user don't want to insert the files for custom object or don't download the file from custom object?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)?